# Video and Audio Editing components

Tags: wpf, video, audio, components, editing

I need to write a video and audio capability in a WPF application. It need to do video and voice capture with basic editing etc.

Does anyone know of any components that could get me going.

Answer (score 2):

[Directshow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454(VS.85).aspx) will be required for audio/video capture from a DV camera unless you are running Windows 7. Then you can use [Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694197(VS.85).aspx). In both cases, you will need .NET interface libraries, which are already completed (Directshow [here](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) and Media Foundation [here](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/)). I'm not sure if the Media Foundation interface library has support for the new capture functionality though.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the [SpeechRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.aspx) class, which is new in .NET 3.0. In fact the entire System.Speech namespace is a good starting place for voice capture.

As for video, [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) is a full-blown FrameworkElement designed to play audio and video, which can be embedded into your WPF applications.